# What does the Orange widget "Image Embedding" do exactly?

Tags: orange

I would need to know what this widget does. What architecture does it use? What dataset has it been trained on? And so on.

Answer (score 1):

The [source](https://github.com/biolab/orange3-imageanalytics/blob/001b8f1e01d39a484a11705dcaef3fe4e47d9fe0/orangecontrib/imageanalytics/image_embedder.py#L25-L39) reveals it's likely Google's [Inception V3](https://www.kaggle.com/google-brain/inception-v3) model.